# Error running 'app': module not specified in android studio

Tags: android

I have written some android code using Intent. While running i am getting module not specified that doesn't allow me to build the project. I have deleted include':app' from settings.gradle file, it doesn't work. Then I have deleted app.iml file still the error cant be resolved